# How can Ready API / SOAP UI Pro creates Webservice Client for WCF webservice with SOAP 1.2?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, cxf-client

I was trying to create Java Web service Client through CXF 3.1.6 , for a CXF Webservice implemented with SOAP 1.2. I always see Cerficate or generated binary token Exception, Where as the service client works through SOAP UI pro.

When i search for the SOAP 1.2 supported CXF webservice client, I see so many places that CXF doesn't support SOAP 1.2. How does SOAP UI pro generates client for this kind of services but we cant achieve it through CXF?

**EDIT :**

Asking this Question,since i am assuming that SOAP UI Pro / Ready API developed their tool based on Java frameworks.